# Getting data from a REST API with no pagination beside page parameter

Tags: javascript, rest, pagination, json-api

I want to move some data from an API into *Elasticsearch* inside my JS app.
The documentation of the API says:

> The API is a classic REST JSON API. {...} To request another page use
>   the page parameter.

Is there a way to find out whether there are additional data when I increase the page parameter incrementally without requesting the non-existing last page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the API provide you with a total count of items?  I would expect a total number of items to be available somewhere (perhaps in the initial call?) - you can then do some simple maths within your JavaScript to figure out how many pages there are and when to stop calling for more.

Comment: No it doesn't! There are limited number of records per page that is fixed, and there is also a limitation on request rate which is why I need to optimize this in the first place.

Comment: If you don't know how many items there are, then I don't see an alternative.  You are only going to know you have reached the end when you request a page, and that page has less than the maximum number of items per page.